# How to make a auto click on a webpage onload?

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage. I want to write a javasript function that will make the html page as a huge excel sheet and put a place holder on a particular row and column. Thus on loading the webpage the place holder will be called by the function and a auto click will be made on that particular row and column.

Does anyone know how to code this function?

I can provide the raw script of the webpage if asked.

Thanks.

Comment: This is disabled by default in any browser with a pop-up blocker. A click event CANNOT be triggered automatically unless it was initiated by an actual user click.

Comment: too little info.  Is this actually opening excel?  Its this just a page that LOOKS like excel?

Answer (score 1):

if foo has a click event then

```
$('#foo').trigger('click');
```

will call the event.

If you are just trying to focus on particular control you can just use :

```
$('#foo').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#ThisMustBeClickedId").trigger('click');
});
```

Provided you may add jQuery, that you can foresee the id, or otherwise select the cell or what it is..

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#your-cell-selector').click();
})
```